# Click event on DOM return father's attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here is a normal HTML file that contain a form and it has some children label, part of codes:

```
<form name="search" action="/cgi-bin/MAPSEARCH2" method="get" onsubmit="var the_result = checkMapNumbers();
return the_result;">
  <input type="hidden" name="LOCAL" value="ALE">
  <table width="700">
    <tbody>

      <td width="20">
       <input type="radio" name="ORDER" value="NAM" checked=""></td>
      <td width="100" valign="top"><font style="color:#330099;">Owner´s Name:</font></td>

   </tbody></table>
</form>
```

And all I want to do is that Add a click function on this all type of "input" labels: and return two values:

**"method" and "action" attribute of its father "form".**

Following is my JS codes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){                                          
    $("input").click(function(){
    var a=$(this).parents("form").method;
    var b=$(this).parents("form").action;    
    $("#test1").text("parents.name:"+ a+ "parents.action"+b);
    });
});
```

But after I click any input element in browser, the output for method and action's values are "undefined". How to return right function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**.prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), it fetches the value of a property

```
var a=$(this).closest("form").prop('method');
var b=$(this).closest("form").prop('action');
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> var a=$(this).parents("form").method;
> ```

Either use simple [native DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement):

```
var a = this.form.method;
```

or [proper](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) jQuery:

```
var a = $(this).parents("form").prop('method');
```

Same for the `action` property.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
   $(document).ready(function(){                                          
        $("input").click(function(){
        var a=$(this).closest("form").attr("method");
        var b=$(this).closest("form").attr("action");    
        $("#test1").text("parents.name:"+ a+ "parents.action"+b);
        });
    });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SDe6h/)